# Image resize while keeping ratio

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I'm listing photos using MySQL:

```
<?php
$a = mysql_query("select * from x");
?>
<?php while ($w=mysql_fetch_array($a)) { ?>
    <img src="<?=$w[url]?>" alt="<?=$w[name]?>" width="150" height="110" />
<? } ?>
```

How can I can maintain the aspect ratio? An image with dimensions of 150x500 pixels becomes very distorted. How can I fix this?

Comment: What you are doing us not image resizing. You only specify the displayed height and width in the browser. It will be shown in with this dimensions but the image size (in MB) stays the same. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify one dimension (either the width or the height but not both) and it will keep the ratio. With CSS you could also specify just the [maximum width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-max-width) and [maximum height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-max-height):

```
<img src="<?=$w[url]?>" alt="<?=$w[name]?>" style="max-width:150px; max-height:110px" />
```

Comment: #photos img {display:block; float:left; width:150px; height:110px; margin-left:12px; border:0;} with this it works good!

Comment: Keep in mind that doing so is not bandwidth friendly. Imagine that you have a 2MB 1024*768 picture and you display it only @ 320*240... Users will still be "forced" to download 2MB of data while a "true" 320*240 picture would be like 100 KB...

Answer (score 3):

Just specifying width-only or height-only in the HTML will keep the ratio.

Or you can actually resize your photos dynamically with a script like the Smart Image resizer: http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

Answer (score 3):

you can get the image size using php:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
$ratio = $height / $width;
$new_width = 150;
$new_height = $ratio * $new_width;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just specify a width, all browsers (that I know of...) will scale the image correctly.

However, you might want to consider making thumbnails if you´re going to load a lot of images.

Answer (score 1):

Setting *both* the width and height of an  forces the browser to rezise it to match what you tell it to.

Setting only one (either width or height) resizes it so that the image's ration is kept.

You can use the PHP function [`getImageSize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to get the image's actual width and height, and then rerform a proportional resize based on `height / width = new_width / new_height`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a resize script to resample (resize) the image.

A good script is located here:
http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

To use:

```
<img src="/image.php?image=/img/test.jpg&amp;width=150&amp;height=500" alt="Test" />
```

I you plan to always use this height/width you could insert the resampled image directly in the database. This way you won't waste space on your server. If you plan to use many height/width or change these sizes in the future, you should keep the originals as you do now.